# VBA - Multiple tabs based on a column without duplicating and renaming tabs

Tags: vba, excel

I have one master data sheet that includes a column with manufacturers' names. The data sheet includes multiple UPC's by the same manufacturer. I need to create multiple tabs by manufacturer (without duplicating) to include all information from the Master sheet for that particular manufacturer. I'd also like each tab to be renamed the manufacturer's name in that praticular sheet.

The trick is: all of my team members have to be able to use this document as a template and we all will have different manufacturers and UPC's. The code needs to be one that doesn't use a set list of manufacturers but pulls information off of a column in the document.

Thank you. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Hi Siddharth - I've tried the following but can't get it to remove duplicates @SiddharthRout

Comment: oops, please see below.  Sub CreateSheetsFromAList()
    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range
     
    Set MyRange = Sheets("All Suppliers Matrix").Range("e7")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet
    Next MyCell
End Sub

Comment: I'm working on getting the sheets split out and named before moving to taking the data from master sheet, per manufacturer in column E, and putting the data into the appropriate newly added tab for each manufacturer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use this code with minor tweaking. Update the sColumn constant to your manufacturer column

```
Sub SplitListIntoWorksheets()
'split list into individual worksheets
Dim lLoop As Long, arrData As Variant
Dim shtData As Worksheet, lgCol As Long, rgSel As range
Dim cUnique As New Collection, shtDest As Worksheet
Const blTitles As Boolean = True                    'true if the data has titles, false otherwise
Const sColumn As String = "A"                       'Which column should the list be split on

application.ScreenUpdating = False
application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
application.DisplayAlerts = False

lgCol = Cells(1, sColumn).Column
Set rgSel = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

Set shtData = ActiveSheet

With shtData
    'load the column into an array for faster processing
    arrData = .range(.Cells(1, sColumn), .Cells(.Rows.Count, sColumn).End(xlUp)).Value

    'load the array content in a collection, to keep individual values only
    On Error Resume Next

    For lLoop = LBound(arrData, 1) To UBound(arrData, 1)
        cUnique.Add arrData(lLoop, 1), CStr(arrData(lLoop, 1))
    Next

    On Error GoTo 0

    'for each individual value, filter the list, copy the results to a new worksheet
    For lLoop = 1 To cUnique.Count
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        rgSel.CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=lgCol - rgSel.CurrentRegion.Column + 1, Criteria1:=cUnique(lLoop)
        Set shtDest = Sheets.Add
        shtDest.Name = "Data " & cUnique(lLoop)
        rgSel.CurrentRegion.Copy shtDest.Cells(1, 1)
    Next

    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With

application.ScreenUpdating = True 'reenable ScreenUpdating
application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! It is erroring out on this line: rgSel.CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=lgCol - rgSel.CurrentRegion.Column + 1, Criteria1:=cUnique(lLoop)

Comment: I should mention, my document has data in rows 1-5 but starting after column H. Data in columns A-G doesnt start until row 6